# Будет ли работать Фласк и Селениум вместе?

Tags: python, selenium, flask

Пишу сайт в котором есть функция парсинга для получения инфы и последующей ее обработки, появился вопрос будет ли работать Фласк и Селениум вместе? Чтобы заработал селениум требовался вебдрайвер, и я не знаю будет ли работать селениум на самом сайте.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под **будет ли работать Фласк и Селениум вместе**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего на сервере понадобится установка не только селениум, но и браузера и вебдрайвера. К тому же понадобится виртуальный графический сервер потому что многие сайты не парсятся  в хедлесс режиме.

В итоге - сделать можно, но нужен сервер с возможностью установить это всё.

Или windows сервер или запускать Xvnc на Линукс. В случае с Линукс можно обрабатывать несколько запросов одновременно.

И лучше разделить фласк и селениум на разные проекты. Пусть селениум забирает задания из очереди и запускается отдельно.